# Ember add list item to array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of products that I'd like to add to an array on another controller for messages. I have created an objectcontroller for the product model so that I can toggle a "selected" attribute (which is working fine) but my observer in the message controller isn't firing. Heres the objectcontroller for the product:

```
App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    selected: false,
    actions:{
        toggleSelected: function(){
            this.set('selected', !this.get('selected'));
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the message controller -- the products are just for a test, but do I (/can I) declare an itemcontroller for a list like this?

```
App.MessagesNewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['product'],
    products: [{name: 'product 1', id: 1}, {name: 'product 2', id: 2}],
    selectedProducts: function(){
        var products = this.get('products');
        return products.filterBy('selected', true);
    }.observes('products.@each.selected')

});
```

and the template:

```
{{#each product in products itemController="product"}}
    <div {{bind-attr class=":well product.selected"}} {{action 'toggleSelected'}}>
        {{product.name}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

I'm very new to Ember so I appreciate any direction or best-practices for this type of thing. Thanks

Note: I'm using ember-data also, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there you are just missing a few things...

1) The data should be loaded in the `model` hook of the `Route. Like this...

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return [{name: 'product 1', id: 1}, {name: 'product 2', id: 2}]
  }
});
```

2) The `App.MessagesController` should be an `Ember.ArrayController` since it's wrapping an array of data. Like this...

```
App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()
```

3) You can specify the `itemController` property on the `App.MessagesController` so that it wraps each item in the array in an item controller.

If you followed all those steps then you would be able to loop through the items in the template by doing something like...

```
{{#each}} <-- if you dont specify what to loop through
              it will loop through the arrayControllers items
              which in this case will be the products wrapped in 
              an itemController
  {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

you would also be able to get the selected items by doing something like...

```
this.filterBy('selected', true);
```

To put it all together it would look like...

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return [{name: 'product 1', id: 1}, {name: 'product 2', id: 2}]
  }
});

App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions:{
        toggleSelected: function(){
            this.toggleProperty('selected');
        }
    }
});

App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'product',
    selectedProducts: function(){
        return this.filterBy('selected', true);
    }.property('@each.selected')

});
```

working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jucab/2/edit

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I'm starting to understand the principles a bit better now. Is there any worry about setting the model in the route to products when the real function of the route is to create a new message (and products are just an associated piece)? Thanks again.

Comment: The model hook should return the data that you would like the controller to wrap. If you would like your message controller to wrap around a bunch of products then it would be fine to return them from the model hook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the property `selected` on the `products`, otherwise it will not propagate back to them when you toggle the property on the controller. See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kiludiwutuyu/1/edit?html,js,output for a working example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One question: I'll be moving to actual data before too long (something like `products = this.store.find('product', {brand: some_brand})`), do you know if I'd still need to initialize the products with the selected attribute there or would they automatically be associated with the productController? I was under the impression that such decorator attributes should be limited to the controller, and I guess I just want to make sure I develop good Ember habits.